# Kotlin coroutines Flow from SharedPreferences and observing stream of data in Repository using GlobalScope versus MainScope

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutinescope, kotlin-coroutines

Hey guys I have question about using kotlin Flow, coroutines and scope. I solved my problem but would like to understand why it works one way and does not other way.

1. I have authentication implemented using AuthRepository 
   this repository has injected

   - service: AuthService
   - userSettings: UserSettings

   2 UserSettings is wrapper around SharedPreferences and provides observable Flows from 
   this SharedPreferences for TOKEN_KEY, USER_ID_KEY, COMPANY_ID_KEY

   ```
       private val tokenPreference: IPreference<Token> = flowPrefs(prefs, GlobalScope).json(
       AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, Token.empty, Token::class.java)
   private val userIdPreference: IPreference<String> = flowPrefs(prefs, GlobalScope).string(
       USER_ID_KEY, "")
   private val companyIdPreference: IPreference<String> = flowPrefs(prefs, GlobalScope).string(
       COMPANY_ID_KEY, "")

   override val isLoggedIn =  combine(tokenPreference.asObservable(), userIdPreference.asObservable(), companyIdPreference.asObservable()) {
           (token, userId, companyId) ->  token != Token.empty && userId != "" && companyId != ""
   }
   ```

here in UserSettings I can set/get each value or observe it via Kotlin Coroutines Flow

```
override var token: Token
        get() = tokenPreference.get()
        set(value) = tokenPreference.set(value)

    override var userId: String
        get() = userIdPreference.get()
        set(value) = userIdPreference.set(value)

    override var companyId: String
        get() = companyIdPreference.get()
        set(value) = companyIdPreference.set(value)

    override val tokenObservable: Flow<Token> = tokenPreference.asObservable()
    override val userIdObservable: Flow<String> = userIdPreference.asObservable()
    override val companyIdObservable: Flow<String> = companyIdPreference.asObservable()
```

3. Observable SharedPreferences using Kotlin Coroutines Flow looks like this

   internal class FlowPreferences(
       private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences,
       private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope
   ) : IFlowPreferences {

   ```
   internal val onKeyValueChange: Flow<String> = callbackFlow {
       val callback = SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { _, key ->
           coroutineScope.launch {
               send(key)
           }
       }

       sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(callback)

       awaitClose {
           Timber.d("close share preferences listener")
           sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(callback)
       }
   }

    override fun string(key: String, defaultValue: String): IPreference<String> =
       Preference(sharedPreferences, key, defaultValue, onKeyValueChange, StringAdapter.shared)
   ```

And Preference implementation enables to access its value directly or via flow()

```
internal class Preference<T>(
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences,
    private val key: String,
    private val defaultValue: T,
    onKeyValueChange: Flow<String>,
    private val adapter: IPreferenceAdapter<T>
) : IPreference<T> {

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    private var values: Flow<T> = onKeyValueChange
                                        .onEach { Timber.d("Emit preference for $key with $it") }
                                        .filter { it == key }
                                        .map { get() }
                                        .onStart { emit(get()) }
                                        .conflate()


    override fun key(): String = key
    override fun defaultValue(): T = defaultValue

@Synchronized
    override fun get(): T {
        return if (!isSet()) {
            defaultValue
        } else {
            adapter.get(sharedPreferences, key)
        }
    }

 override fun asObservable(): Flow<T> = values
```

4. Then inside my AuthRepository I have such code to thats mainly dow 2 things 
   A) enables to initiate login with login() function 
   B) observes/collects flows from token and userId to make request to API for user and company 
    it also manages token/userId/companyId and other SharedPreferences user sessions values storage

   init {

   ```
       userSettings.tokenObservable
           .filter {
               Timber.d("Token observed: $it")
               it != Token.empty
           }
           .flatMapMerge {
               Timber.d("Token > User request $it")
               userRepo.loadCurrentUser()
           }
           .onEach { Timber.d("User Id Response $it") }
           .mapNotNull { it.data?.id }
           .onEach { userId ->
               userSettings.userId = userId

               if (appSettings.shouldUseBiometry != userId) {
                   appSettings.shouldUseBiometry = ""
               }

               Timber.d("Synced user: $userId")
           }
           .catch {
               userSettings.token = Token.empty
               userSettings.userId = ""
               userSettings.companyId = ""

               Timber.d(it, "Synced user: exception")
           }
           .onCompletion {
               Timber.d(it, "Synced user: completed")
           }
           .launchIn(GlobalScope)


       userSettings.userIdObservable
           .onEach {
               Timber.d("User id on each $it")
           }
           .filter {
               Timber.d("User Id observed: $it")
               it != ""
           }
           .flatMapMerge { userId ->
               Timber.d("User id > Company id request $userId")
               companyRepo.loadCompanyOf(userId)
           }
           .mapNotNull { it.data?.id }
           .onEach { companyId ->
               userSettings.companyId = companyId

               Timber.d("Synced company: $companyId")
               // TODO: start socket manager here
           }
           .catch {
               userSettings.token = Token.empty
               userSettings.userId = ""
               userSettings.companyId = ""

               Timber.d(it, "Synced company: exception")
           }
           .onCompletion {
               Timber.d(it, "Synced company: completed")
           }
           .launchIn(GlobalScope)


       userSettings.companyIdObservable
           .onEach {
               Timber.d("New company id: $it")
           }
           .launchIn(GlobalScope)
   ```

   }

   override val isLoggedIn: Flow = userSettings.isLoggedIn.distinctUntilChanged { old, new ->
       Timber.d("is logged in $old to $new")
       old == new
   }

   //region LOGIN/LOGOUT
   override suspend fun login(email: String, password: String): Flow> {

   ```
   val clientId = AppConstants(app).CLIENT_ID
   val clientSecret = AppConstants(app).CLIENT_SECRET

   return object: FlowNetworkResource<Token>() {

       override suspend fun createCall(): Flow<Response<Token>> {
           return service.login(email, password, clientId, clientSecret)
       }
   }.asFlow()
    .onEach {
       when(it.status) {
           Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
               Timber.d("Token request success!")
               userSettings.token = it.data!!

               secureStore.putString(SECURED_EMAIL_KEY, email)
               secureStore.putString(SECURED_PASSWORD_KEY, password)
           }
           else -> {
               Timber.d("Token request other!")
               userSettings.token = Token.empty
               userSettings.userId = ""
               userSettings.companyId = ""
           }
       }
    }
   ```

   }

So as you can see here in Repository and User Settings class I am using GlobalScope to be able to launch/collect this flow !

But it doesn't work and I do not understand why, I have spend A LOT OF TIME to find this bug that GlobalScope which I thought that has lifespan of entire application is deallocated? or usually immediately stops observing stream of data from flow/shared preferences.

I found it by moving my code shared preferences observations to ViewModel and then I've used viewModelScope and I've noticed that there flow is constantly observing and onEach { } or collect { } are always executed.

```
val tokenFlow = flowPrefs(prefs, viewModelScope).json(
        UserSettings.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, Token.empty, Token::class.java).observe()

    init {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            tokenFlow.collect {
                Timber.d("[TokenFlow] Token $it")
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I tried there GlobalScope and it just observed initial onStart() default value emission and stopped observing later emissions

```
val tokenFlow = flowPrefs(prefs, GlobalScope).json(
        UserSettings.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, Token.empty, Token::class.java).observe()

    init {

        GlobalScope.launch {
            tokenFlow.collect {
                Timber.d("[TokenFlow] Token $it")
            }
        }
    }
```

Above doesn't work

Then I found that using `MainScope()` works correctly, similar to **viewModelScope**. it is just **SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main**

ContextScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main)

```
val tokenFlow = flowPrefs(prefs, MainScope()).json(
        UserSettings.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, Token.empty, Token::class.java).observe()

    init {

        MainScope().launch {
            tokenFlow.collect {
                Timber.d("[TokenFlow] Token $it")
            }
        }
    }
```

I do not understand why GlobalScope cannot be used here, why MainScope() and vieWModelScope works.

Repository, UserSettings are Singletons injected using Dagger 2, they are I think allocated as there is 1 Fragment > 1 ViewModel > 1 Repository > 1 UserSettings reference kept

I've noticed that I can also try to implement my own scope using CoroutineScope interface SuperivisorJob and Dispatchers.IO

```
val scope: CoroutineScope = object : CoroutineScope {
        override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.IO
    }

    val tokenFlow = flowPrefs(prefs, scope).json(
        UserSettings.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, Token.empty, Token::class.java).observe()

    init {

        scope.launch {
            tokenFlow.collect {
                Timber.d("[TokenFlow] Token $it")
            }
        }
    }
```